# Checking if the right instance of an app is running locally _before_ presenting a link in a webpage

Tags: android, ios, security, deep-linking

I’m creating an application that at some point requires the user to confirm their email address or phone number. For confirmation purposes a link is sent to the user. Naturally, user can switch to another application on their iOS device to open the link or they may use another device to do so.

I would like to implement some method for detecting if the user opened the link on the same device that app is running and if so initiate a redirect back to the app to resume the process (app is registered as a handler of a specific URI scheme). In case user opened the link on another device that has the same app installed I don’t want the redirect to happen.

Is it possible from the context of Safari JavaScript to find out if the page is being open on the same device that a certain instance of app is running? (The app could be and is likely in background so I don't suppose running an http service in it would be of any good)

I could open a special page from the app that would drop a cookie that later can be detected but that wouldn’t be nice since user will have to see browser flicker even if for a second (before the page redirects him back to the app)

Are there any good solutions to this problem in the post UDID ios world?
Is this any easier on android?